# validate() returns false but getErrors() returns an empty array - Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am building a yii application. Heres the code -:

```
    $id = 2;

    $model = Page::model()->findByPk(2);
    $model->title = 'HeyMan';

    if($model->validate())
    {
        echo 'Validation retuned true';
    }
    else
    {
        $array = $model->getErrors();
        $message = 'Validation returned false';
    }
```

And the result is that the validate() returns false while getErrors() returns an empty array.  Whats the problem here ? Thanks

Comment: Can you post validation rules in Page model?

Comment: Hi! I've got the similaire problem. When i'm trying to submit the form the rules work good because if I let an input empty and if it must not be empty according to the rules in the BaseClass the form don't submit but the problem is: my validate message is empty it doesnt say that 'X input must not be empty'. Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 7):

Did you use the **beforeSave** function in your model? Then make sure to return the parent beforeSave:

```
return parent::beforeSave();
```

Comment: can you explain why ? i got same problem .

Comment: I have added above code but still same issue exists. Please share more details around it.

Answer (score 0):

Posible solutions:

1. Input does not validate. The rules array in your model if configured
   in order to validate input. It could theoretically be possible that
   title is set to be integer only or something like that. You should
   look into what rules you have set.
2. Model issues. This is more likely because you don't get any errors. All functions in the model must return true otherwise you will get these kind of issues. As far as as return parent::beforeSave() goes, you need to return that because your model extends CActiveRecord and when you create beforeSave() or beforeValidate() or afterSave() you are overriding those methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.In the controller after form submitting validate() returns false while getErrors() returns an empty array. I used beforeSave() method in the model the wrong way. When I fixed the usage of beforeSave() the validatin and model saving started working the normal way.

The solution for me was:

```
// in the model class 

public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    // some code here ...

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Not only calling the **return parent::beforeSave();** ,

but calling with the  **$insert**  parameter

like this: **return parent::beforeSave($insert);**

Comment: It's not entirely clear how this relates to the original question, which seems to be more about page validation than saving. Suggest you might want to edit your answer to make your code look more similar to that in the original question.